# Editing MP3 metadata on a file-like object in Python?

Tags: python, mp3, metadata, id3

We're generating MP3 files on the fly in Python, and need to edit the ID3 headers in-memory using a file-like object.

All the ID3 libraries on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=id3&submit=search) *appear* to require you to pass a filesystem path as a string. I find this rather frustrating!

Writing our generated MP3 out to disk (or ramdisk) just to add ID3 tags is unacceptable for a number of reasons, especially performance.

*Given the plentitude of ID3 libraries*, is there an ID3 library that simply works with file-like objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer seems to be that no such animal exists. The advantages of programming to an interface are apparently lost on the python MP3 frame hackers. We solved the problem by modifying an existing library.

Answer (score 3):

For those finding this answer in the distant future, [mutagen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mutagen/1.37), has worked perfectly for me and the constructor for one of its MP3 objects takes *either* a file path *or* a file-like object (the docs call it a 'filething').

From https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/filelike.html:

> The first argument passed to a FileType or Metadata can either be a file name or a file-like object, such as StringIO (BytesIO in Python 3) and mutagen will figure out what to do.
>
> ```
> MP3("myfile.mp3")
> MP3(myfileobj)
> ```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer as of 2019 aka "distant future" :).
BTW, if you are using Django, and you have a model with a FileField, you can just pass the FieldFile object to mutagen and it will work as expected. E.g. if you have a model with field `audio` and you have an instance of a model `instance`, you can do `mutagen.File(instance.audio)` and you can access `info` as expected

Answer (score 0):

Does StringIO help? http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

Comment: The problem is, all the libraries I've seen won't work w/ StringIO, or anything like it, because they require a filesystem path.

Comment: and you don't want to modify one of the simpler libs?

Comment: Would you recommend a simple one to modify?

Comment: I'd just browse the libs on PyPI to find one that does what you want and is small.  You may be able to just redefine open to take a string (rather than a filename) and return fh, where fh = StringIO.StringIO(string_variable).

Answer (score -1):

AFAIR tags are appended to the end of file. You might want to study the format and make a simple library yourself, that should not be very difficult.

Also, you could consider storing them temporary on a filesystem like tmpfs (ramdisk).

Comment: Yeah. As for tmpfs, it's too hackish. I already have the object in memory--why do I need to copy it to work with it?

Comment: Because you'll spare your programming time. Copying in RAM is relatively cheap (5MB file takes 0.05s on my 3-year-old laptop). So the deciding factor is how you value your effort. The only thing that could be more important is the server load introduced by that copying, compared to other tasks your server needs to do... and I know nothing about your code, so decide yourself.

Comment: You're totally right, and we may end up doing that or roll our own frame-hacking strategy. The point of the question, however, was to avoid all that by discovering an out-of-the-box solution that would spare us programming time. Hacking frames or hacking servers are more work, not less, and outside the scope of this question.